# Allow/deny image hotlinking with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hotlinking

So I've got this in my site .htaccess file to prevent hotlinking of images, JS and CSS from all other domains.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|js|css)$ - [F,NC,L]
```

Question: How would I selectively allow one or two domains to hotlink?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?otherdomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|js|css)$ - [F,NC,L]
```

Will work, as this says.

"Refererr is not nothing, and referer is not matching mydomain and referer is not matching otherdomain.

If it were the case that you were trying to do the opposite (blacklist a set of domains from hotlinking) you'd do something like

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www\.)?baddomain1\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www\.)?baddomain2\.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|js|css)$ - [F,NC,L]
```

Comment: Jeez, that was easy. Should have realized that myself! Thanks!

Comment: How to define the hostname dynamically?

Comment: is this work for sub domain also? like nv.example.com?

Answer (score 3):

[Just add another condition](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/hotlinking/) before the RewriteRule for each domain you want to allow.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !friendlysite\.com [NC]
```

(presumably you don't care if the request is via http or https or whatever, so you can leave that out to make it more generic)