# Protect folder from remote access in PHP

Tags: php, security, directory

I have a project that my client upload a lot of files to a folder on the server. That files can be downloaded using a link on his administrator page on the system (in PHP).

How can I disable the direct access to this files (in browser address)?

Comment: This question comes up often.  Try some of these and also a search of the site.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990337/how-to-protect-against-direct-access-to-images OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409496/prevent-direct-access-to-a-php-include-file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the upload directory somewhere *outside* of the web root. For example, if Apache (or whatever web server you are using) is configured with a web root of /var/www, but the uploaded files into e.g. /var/uploads, which guarantees that no one can every directly download them (at least via your web server).

Then use a PHP script as a stand-in proxy that first checks that the user is authenticated and authorized, then uses e.g. the `passthru()` function (after setting appropriate headers, of course) to let the user download the file.