# How I forbid people to put my links (images, .css files and .js files) into their websites?

Tags: php, apache

I think it was discussed, but I I can't find the thread. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245869/allow-deny-image-hotlinking-with-htaccess This should help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Apache, use .htaccess to block requests that don't provide a HTTP_REFERER from your own domain.

http://www.htaccess-guide.com/deny-visitors-by-referrer/

Comment: This is spoofable, is it not?

Comment: Well I felt it should be stated, as this is a rather weak solution if he really wants to `forbid` access.