# How to prevent javascript linking

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm serving a javascript file from my server. How do I prevent direct linking to it so that the server doesn't get used to serve the javascript to other websites?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [usual techniques for blocking hotlinking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245869/allow-deny-image-hotlinking-with-htaccess) apply.

Comment: Yes, but there are some Javascript techniques as well, like [Martin's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5429700/247696).

Answer (score 3):

To discourage hotlinking you could put annoying code in the script and have that execute if `window.location` doesn't match your own site:

```
while (window.location.hostname !== 'www.example.com')
  alert('Plz stop hotlinking');
```

Comment: but that would still serve the file and consume my bandwidth.

Comment: @sami yes, but you would render the script unusable to others and nobody in their right mind would link to it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no good way to do so. However, you could do some referer checks or check the values from the `location` object and make the JavaScript do bad things when embedded from a different site.

When doing referer checks don't forget to allow an empty referer as some people block referers.