# How to prevent user to access css files and images via the url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-401

I am using `.htaccess` to prevent user to access files through url.
The line

```
RewriteRule ^frontend/assets/css/(.+) index [L,R]
```

works fine. It prevents users to access css files.
However,

```
RewriteRule ^frontend/assets/images/(.+) index [L,R] //Images
```

as well as

```
RewriteRule ^frontend/assets/js/(.+) index [L,R] //Javascript files
```

do not work.
I have tried multiple [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118482/deny-access-to-one-specific-folder-in-htaccess) but still I can access `js` and `images (png and svg)` files from the url.
Is there a way to handle this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please following rules at the top of your htaccess rules file. You need not to create 3 separate rules for 3 conditions, you can use regex here and can do a 401 redirect for all of 3 strings(js/images/css) in a single rule itself.

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^frontend/assets/(?:images|css|js) - [R=401,NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you @RavinderSingh13. I am facing another issue. There are 2 directories in the image directory. When I do `RewriteRule ^frontend/assets/images/(?:dir1|dir2) - [R=401,NC,L]`, the access is only denied to one directory.

Comment: @Kyv, sure, could you please open a new question for same, we could discuss it there but please post your efforts(like you mentioned here code), cheers.

Comment: Sure. The question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70504461/how-to-prevent-user-to-access-images-in-multiple-directories-via-the-url

Answer (score 0):

actually, this helped me: [Allow/deny image hotlinking with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245869/allow-deny-image-hotlinking-with-htaccess)

small video with the same example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PsbpuH_e12E

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(subdomain\.)?domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpeg|png|jpg|js|css)$ - [F,NC,L]
```