# How to prevent user to access images in multiple directories via the url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-401

I am using `.htaccess` to prevent user to access images through url.
Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70503909/how-to-prevent-user-to-access-css-files-and-images-via-the-url) question, I could prevent users to access `.js` files.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^frontend/assets/(?:js) - [R=401,NC,L]
```

However, when I applied the same rules in order to denied access to `dir1` and `dir2`, the access is only denied to images in directory `dir1`.

```
RewriteRule ^frontend/assets/images/(?:dir1|dir2) - [R=401,NC,L]
```

Is there a way to handle this and prevent users to access files in directory `dir2` as well ?

Comment: could you please do mention sample url which you are hitting?

Comment: I am working locally (localhost), If I understood your question correctly

Comment: oh ok, actually I was saying if you are hitting url like: `http://localhost:80/frontend/assets/images/dir1` etc?

Comment: Ah oK. I can acces this `http://localhost/free/frontend/assets/images/users/3wb2M.png` . But the access to this  `http://localhost/free/frontend/assets/images/uploads/3wb2M.png` is denied.

Comment: sure, how about using `RewriteRule ^free/frontend/assets/images/(?:users|uploads) - [R=401,NC,L]` this one once?

Comment: The same problem remains.

Comment: ok, do you have any other rules before this rule(which I pinged in previous comment)?

Comment: Yes, I have `RewriteEngine On` and `RewriteRule ^frontend/assets/(?:images|css|js) - [R=401,NC,L]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try following htaccess rules file. Apart from fixing regex we need to be careful on where we need to place the rule. So place this rule before your previously used rule(s).

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
##Enabling RewriteEngine here...
RewriteEngine On
##Rewrite rule for images with checking users OR uploads here...
RewriteRule ^free/frontend/assets/images/(?:users|uploads) - [R=401,NC,L]
##Rewrite rule for images OR css OR js folders here....
RewriteRule ^frontend/assets/(?:images|css|js) - [R=401,NC,L]
```